# TypeError на строке 3: filter expected 2 arguments, got 1 lambda python filter

Tags: python, list, filter, lambda

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
n = int(input())
filter_number = list(filter(lambda x, y:x < y))
print(filter_number(a,n))
```

программа должна возвращать значение элемента массива а < n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
n = int(input())
filter_number = list(filter(lambda x: x < n, a))
print(filter_number)
```